# How to build python package for other PC?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

### Environment

PC1: Dev-machine, online, Python install dir: `C:\Python310`
PC2: Target machine, offline, Python install dir: `C:\Program Files\Python310`

### Doing

1. Write source and run command in workdir `pip install -t ./out ./` on PC1.
2. Copy files under out dir from PC1 to PC2.
3. Open term and invoke exe file on PC2.

Then I got message `Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Python310\python.exe"  "C:\Program Files\Python310\Scripts\my_app.exe" ': ??????????????????`.

How can I build for PC2?

### Folder structure

```
┗━ my_app
    ┣━ setup.py
    ┗━ my_app
        ┣━ __init__.py
        ┣━ __main__.py
        ┗━ main.py
```

### File contents:

#### setup.py

```python
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name = 'my_app',
    packages = find_packages(),
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': [
            'my_app = my_app.main:main',
        ],
    },
)
```

#### my_app/__main__.py

```python
from .main import main

main()
```

#### my_app/main.py

```python
def main():
    print('hello world')
```

### Constraints

- without cx_freeze, pyinstaller, py2exe or similer third party packages
- actual my_app requires external packages(ex: [tqdm](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/))

Comment: can you please elaborate.  it appears as though you want to move a project from one PC to another ?  is this the case ?

Comment: I'd like to move the built product of the project. The project is for PC2, but PC2 only connected to closed network(intranet), so cannot resolve published packages on pypi when install.
I tried to use cx_freeze and pyinstaller, but generated exe file didn't work well.

Comment: what stops you from copying all the files to a medium like a usb drive and pasting from there ?

Answer (score 0):

Run command `python setup.py bdist` and copy `dist/my_app...zip` content to target machine, its resolved my question.

https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/builtdist.html